# Django: Showing username and not ID, how?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following serializers class.

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'active', 'type', 'user')
```

When listing all profiles the user field shows the user ID. How do I change this to show the user.username? I know with my models I just add this to my meta class, but as did not create the user model (its part of Django). How do I tell Django when calling a user to show the username and not the id?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two obvious ways you can deal with this:

Firstly you can use the `dotted.notation` to force the [source argument](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields.html#core-arguments) of the `user` field to be `user.username` instead of the default `user`.

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.Field(source='user.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'active', 'type', 'user')
```

Note that `Field` is a standard read-only field, so you wouldn't be able to update the user using this serializer.

Alternatively, if you want user to be a writable field, you can use a [SlugRelatedField](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#slugrelatedfield) like so...

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'active', 'type', 'user')
```

If you want you could also use the second approach but use a read-only field, by adding `read_only=True` to the `SlugField`.

Comment: :p  Hopefully all helpful stuff and that you're making progress.

Answer (score 5):

This thread is old, but since I encoutered the same issue recently I would like to add the modern answer to it.
We must user the built-in SerializerMethodField() of DRF like this:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  def get_user(self, obj):
      return obj.user.username

  class Meta:
      model = Profile
      fields = ('id', 'name', 'active', 'type', 'user')
```