# How to get a username instead of an id?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I want to write a tweeter-like app and I'd like to get the author username instead of the author id. However now I'm having this error when I create a new Tweet: NOT NULL constraint failed: tweets_tweet.author_id

I first tried to use the get_*field* method in my seriliazer.

Here is the model:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True, 
    blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    datestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    nb_likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    nb_comments = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        related_name = "tweets",
        related_query_name = "post",
        null=False
    )
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.content[:10]) + '-' + randomString()
        super(Tweet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is my Serializer :

```
class TweetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    author = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_author(self, obj):
        return obj.user.username

    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = ["content", "author", "nb_likes", "nb_comments", "slug"]


    def to_representation(self, obj):
        representation = super().to_representation(obj)
        if obj.nb_likes > 50:
        representation['super_popular'] = True
        return representation
```

and my JSON looks likes :

```
{
"content": "blablabla",
"author_username": "valentin",
"author": 1,
"nb_likes": 0,
"nb_comments": 0,
"slug": "blablabla-2159054817"
}
```

Comment: Would you mind pasting the stack trace?

Comment: you didn't say when you get this error, but it seems you're writing to the db so you're using the serializer also to create new objects. You can't replace the `author` field like that, since you're breaking how an `author` should be written when creating the `tweet`.

Comment: it happens when I'm trying to create a new Tweet object from the drf interface @dirkgroten. I would like to get the author.username displayed but still being able to create new object without getting an error

Comment: What's the field you use to create a new `Tweet`? How does the JSON look like? You're saying you want to "get" username instead of id but if you're using the serializer to create new objects you should also tell us what input you're passing to your serializer.

Comment: @dirkgroten I updated the post with the JSON format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), `SerializerMethodField` is a read-only field. So you've made `author` read-only, whereas you still want to be able to create a `Tweet` with an `author`.

Now if you want to use `username` instead of `id` for both read and write, and assuming `username` is unique, then [this document](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/?q=SerializerMethodField#serializer-relations) shows you the options you have for related fields: The `SlugRelatedField` with `slug_field` set to `author` would allow you do pass in "author" as username and return it also as "username":

```
author = SlugRelatedField(slug_field="username", queryset=User.objects.all())
```

Note that this means your input JSON needs to be changed, because right now the "author" key maps to an id.

But if you want to use the `id` as input and the `username` as output, then you need to make it a custom relational field, with different *representation* than *internal value*:

```
class TweetAuthorField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.username
```

I'm subclassing `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` here, because it already does all the correct things for mapping data to the object using the primary key (the id), so there's no need to rewrite that code.

Comment: thank you for your complete answer. when I try to use the slugrelatedfield I have this error :  Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True'. Being new to drf and django, I really do not know what to do

Comment: by the way this post  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896825/django-showing-username-and-not-id-how], seems close to my problem. The only difference is that I want to create object from the drf interface, but is it really usefull ?

Comment: updated. the error told you exactly what was needed: provide a queryset.

Comment: as I said, I updated my answer. But the error also said it: "Relational field must provide a queryset", so it's in the relational field (SlugRelatedField). And probably the line of the error would show you where also.

Comment: Omg it worked ! Thank you for your time, and sorry for being retarded !